# Dividing up a char array to different values in struct

Tags: c

Through a tcp socket I get a string like this: "SmallTitle fromhost 9595".

**Upon reciving it I would like to divide it in to a struct so it's easier to work with.**

This is what I have come up with. But there are problems. 1 it is nasty. 2 When printing the struct in the end i recieve garbage output after the string. See output example at the bottom. Should not printf stop at '\0'? Then it might be missing such.

```
struct recieved {
    char what[50];
    char from[50];
    int value;
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct recieved leaderRec;

    char *word;
    char buf[] = "leadervalue host 9569"; //Example recieved input from socket.

    word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    int i = 0;
    int count = 1;

    do{
        if((buf[i] == ' ') || (buf[i+1] == '\0')){
            //End of word
            //word[strlend(word)+1] = '\0';
            //printf("%s\n", word);
            if(count == 3){
                //The value is here
                //get the last number
                strncat(word,&buf[i], 1);
                leaderRec.value = atoi(word);
                //printf("%d\n", value);
            }

            if(count == 1)
                strncpy(leaderRec.what, word, strlen(word));
            else if(count == 2)
                strncpy(leaderRec.from, word, strlen(word));
            free(word);
            word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            //printf("%d\n",i );
            //printf("%s\n", &buf[i]);
            strncat(word,&buf[i], 1);
        }
        //printf("%s", &buf[i]);
        //printf("%d -", i);
        i++;
    } while(buf[i] != '\0');

    printf("%s\n", leaderRec.what);
    printf("%s\n", leaderRec.from);
    printf("%d\n", leaderRec.value);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
leadervalue
host__vdso_get
9569
```

Any better ways to do this?
How would I avoid the garbage output at the second print in the example output?

Comment: Please write code as though humans will read it.

Comment: Note that the way you are using `malloc()` makes it look like you don't understand what `malloc()` is for. Likely your `strncpy()` migh be a little bit wrong. I just never use it, because IMHO it's better to use `memcpy()` and  write the `'\0'` by hand.

Comment: In `strncat(word,&buf[i], 1);` the buffer data is unintialised so you can't use that. Use `strncpy`. Oh whoops mybad - that's conditional on being a later loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane And doesn't that just copy 1 byte? So the code would iterate every time the whole string just to append a single byte. Isn't it a lot better to keep current string length somewhere and just append the single character at the right position?

Comment: This is mystery to me — `word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50); /*...*/ free(word); word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);`

Comment: Use `strtok` ..

Comment: @MFisherKDX That seems like a much simpler solution than I managed to make. I will try that.

Comment: @Starlord however you process `buf` you still need to initialise `word` which is not done by `malloc` or by `strncat`.

Comment: the reason for the garbage is that  you have not zero terminated you strings. Since your code is impossible to follow its hard to point to where it should be done. use strtok

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for pointing that out. I think strok is the way to go. @ pm100 the manual says strncat should always put '\0' at the end of appending a string.

Comment: Yes it does, but the *target* to which it is concatenated must be a valid zero-terminated C string.

Comment: @WeatherVane aha. Now I know. Thanks all

Comment: ... which you could acheive with `word = malloc(50); *word = '\0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there are problems. 1 it is nasty. 2 When printing the struct in
>   the end i recieve garbage output after the string.

The "garbage" prints, as have been noted in the comments, are because you are not properly null terminating your strings.  For instance, you are not initializing `word` to an empty string (single null character) before calling `strncat`.

> Any better ways to do this?

Most certainly.  I'd suggest using `strtok` as so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct received {
    char what[50];
    char from[50];
    int value;
};

int main(void)
{
  char buf[] = "leadervalue host 9569";
  struct received leaderRec; 
  /* Initialize leaderRec here */      
  memset(&leaderRec, 0, sizeof(leaderRec));

  char *s = strdup(buf);
  char *p = strtok(s, " ");
  if (p != NULL) {
     strncpy(leaderRec.what, p, sizeof(leaderRec.what));
     p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  if (p != NULL) {
     strncpy(leaderRec.from, p, sizeof(leaderRec.from));
     p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  if (p != NULL) {
     leaderRec.value = atoi(p);
  }
  free(s);

  printf("%s %s %d\n", leaderRec.what, leaderRec.from, leaderRec.value);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's true, I'll delete my first comment: I gave UV before commenting anyway.